# Significance of datapoint outside prediction band

Tags: regression, p-value, linear, text-mining, prediction-interval

With linear regression I am plotting 25 bodies of text with their vocabulary count (independent variable X) and occurrence of a particular word (for example: "this").

I have a linear regression of different texts with a P-value of 0.2. R-squared is 0.82. I have calculated the prediction interval.

I have seen another author claim that a new plotted point (so a new body of text with a certain amount of words and certain amount of "this" occurrences) that was inside the prediction band was not significantly divergent from the trend to require explanation.

Is it true that only data outside the prediction interval is significantly divergent from the trend? Can I still draw conclusions about datapoints being inside/outside the prediction interval when my p-value is this high?

Comment: For a start, what percentage (y%) of records falls out of a x% (what is x) prediction band? If x% is approximately the same as y%, then that is a lot less concerning that a very strong difference between the two percentages. It also depends on what the purpose of your model is, if it is prediction with well quantified uncertainty, then I'd worry about it more than for some other contexts.

Comment: Thank you! I hope I have clarified it a bit now. I should note that I am an absolute beginner in these things. The purpose of the model is qualifying the significance of the divergence of one text to a larger body of texts. (i.e. is this text so unsimilar to the other texts that it requires explanation)